# Is refresh token mandatory for TD Ameritrade API?

Tags: java, ameritrade

I'm trying to use this Java library for TD Ameritrade https://github.com/studerw/td-ameritrade-client

Here is the starting code

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("tda.client_id", "XXX@AMER.OAUTHAP"); // I have this 
    props.setProperty("tda.token.refresh", "XXX");  // I don't have this
```

I have a `client_id`, a.k.a. `consumer key`

But I don't have a refresh token. I only want to use the Quotes API, I don't want to make any actual trades. I'm able to test the `consumer key` here https://developer.tdameritrade.com/quotes/apis/get/marketdata/quotes and it works great. Do I have to obtain refresh token too? Is it mandatory? Is there any way to use `consumer key` only without the `refresh token`?

Here https://developer.tdameritrade.com/quotes/apis/get/marketdata/quotes it says "Authorization Token aka Refresh token  is Optional", so is it really "Optional"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, if you have tokens, you will get more up to date quotes. If you do not, you will get delayed data:

> Pass your OAuth User ID to make an unauthenticated request for
> **delayed** data.

If you want more realtime data (I do not have an Ameritrade account, not sure exactly what the delay difference is), you can use tokens:

> (**Optional**) The Authorization token to validate the request. **Not
> required** for un-authenticated requests

*(Un-authenticated requests being the above delayed route)*

Alternatively, if you want a Refresh Token, which expires every 90 days and is used to gain an Access Token (expires every 30 minutes), the steps are listed here:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/simple-auth-local-apps

> That will give you a refresh token that you can use for 90 days to
> **request access tokens** and allow you to authenticate without needing a
> server. Note that you will need to update your app's refresh token at
> least once every 90 days to keep it functioning.

Again, I do not have a TD Ameritrade account to personally confirm this, but looks like you have at least two options to get Quotes.

Further FAQ resources:

- https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/authentication-faq